# What is the right way to get Public propertyinfo only?

Tags: c#, reflection

is the following the most convenient way?

```
type.GetProperties().Where(pinfo=> pinfo.CanRead).ToArray();
```

all i want to do is to ignore the following

```
private object prop {get;set;}
protected object prop {get;set;}
```

but not

```
public object prop {get;set;}
public object prop {get;private set;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload which takes `BindingFlags` as an argument: [Type.GetProperties Method (BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Quick test shows it returns exactly what you need:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private object prop1 { get; set; }
    protected object prop2 { get; set; }

    public object prop3 { get; set; }
    public object prop4 { get; private set; }
}
```

```
var prop = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Return 2 elements: `prop3` and `prop4` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that simply `GetProperties`? By default you'll get only public properties.

```
var properties = type.GetProperties();
```

Note: This includes static properties and write-only properties also, but I believe no one design a property with set only accessor.